# Wordpress - fullwidth category edit page

Tags: wordpress, categories

can you please help me, how I can make category edit page fullwidth? Thank you very much!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbcWc.jpg

I am using ACF plugin and if I change css in acf-input.css of this plugin, its fullscreen. But until the plugin is updated.

```
#edittag {
max-width: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add CSS to a custom plugin or child theme in order to make it withstand updates. I'd recommend creating a child theme of your chosen theme. More info:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Keep in mind that area to the right in your screenshot may be reserved for other admin items, so you should probably do some more specific CSS targeting by looking at the body class of your category edit page.

Something like

```
.wp-admin.some-class-only-on-that-edit-page #edittag {
    max-width: unset;
}
```

to enqueue admin styles, use the admin_enqueue_scripts hook in your functions.php file. note that the function for getting the stylesheet directory is different for using a child theme. if using a child theme and your admin.css file is in root of your child theme, this would go in your functions.php file:

```
function yourthemename_admin_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/admin.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'yourthemename_admin_style');
```

if you're using a custom theme and not a child theme change get_stylesheet_directory_uri to get_template_directory_uri.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I am using my custom template I code - http://test010.jasika.cz, but if I want to edit anything from core of WP and I change css of any element of core of WP in my style.css, it doesnt make anything.
How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: you need to enqueue admin styles in your functions.php file on the admin_enqueue_scripts hook.